# Resize zfs pool

Tags: freebsd, zfs, digital-ocean, bsd

We are using Digital Oceans block storage feature on our FreeBSD system.

When we add a new block storage we get:

```
da0 at vtscsi0 bus 0 scbus0 target 0 lun 1
da0: <DO Volume 1.5.> Fixed Direct Access SPC-3 SCSI device
da0: 300.000MB/s transfers
da0: Command Queueing enabled
da0: 5120MB (10485760 512 byte sectors)
da0 at vtscsi0 bus 0 scbus0 target 0 lun 1
```

and it works fine. We created a zpool and a zfs dataset. 
On the zpool we set:
`zpool set autoexpand=on tank`

And then we resize the block storage disc on Digital Ocean.

**Here is our problem**

`geom disk list` does not pick up the change **UNTIL** we export the zpool. And we cannot resize the zpool until system has recognized the new size for the disc.

If we export the zpool it will correctly show the new size with `geom disk list`. But not until we have done so.

Now we can run `zpool online -e tank da0` and the pool and its datasets will have the new size.

We have tried running `camcontrol rescan da0`but to no avail.

Is there any way to force a rescan to recognize the new disk size? Because now we have to export/unmount all the datasets, and that is not possible on an live envorionment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
camcontrol reprobe da0
```

will reprobe. after that I only needed: `zpool online -e tank da0`